# Why the first php file is returning wrong information, while the second returns the right information?

Tags: php, json

I'm new to php and I could really use some help.

I have a php file that returns the information requested in the wrong order or not at all, changing the variables in the php file i manage to get the desired results.

Still, how is it possible given the following files?

First php file the returns WORNG INFO

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "user");

    //$idquestion = @($_POST['idquestion']);
    //$category = @($_POST['category']);
    $idquestion="1";
    $category="computers";

    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM question WHERE idquestion=? AND category=?;");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "is", $idquestion,  $category);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $success, $idquestion, $question, $id);

    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = false;

    while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
        $response["success"] = true;
        $response["idquestion"] = $idquestion;
        $response["question"] = $question;
        $response["id"] = $id;
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Output

```
{"success":true,"idquestion":"Top programming languages?","question":"computers","id":1}
```

And the second php file returns the CORRECT INFO

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "id8963226_user", "parola123", "id8963226_user");

    //$idquestion = @($_POST['idquestion']);
    //$category = @($_POST['category']);
    $idquestion="4";
    $category="computers";

    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM question WHERE idquestion=? AND category=?;");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "is", $idquestion,  $category);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $success, $idquestion, $question, $id);

    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = false;
    $response["idquestion"] = $idquestion;

    while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
        $response["success"] = true;
        $response["question"] = $idquestion;
        $response["id"] = $id;
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Output

```
{"success":true,"idquestion":"1","question":"Top programming languages?","id":1}
```

How is the logic behind the first php file given me those results?
Basically I want the LAST RESULTS to work without messing up the code.

Any opinion is welcomed. Thank you.

Comment: Next time, please explicitly explain the differences, comparing 2 blocks of code vertically is hard...

Comment: The problem is I need the output to be idquestion=1, question=top programming lang, id=1

Comment: As you can see the first php returns idquestion=top programming lang, which is entirely wrong

Comment: Still can't work out the actual problem. You're saying that's wrong, because? I mean, we can't see your DB or data, so we're very much in the dark here.

Comment: It isnt returning wrong info, you are coding it wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your query you are using `SELECT *` in other words you are letting Mysql return all the columns in an order it decides. This order will probably be the order in which the columns were defined, but basically you are not in control of the column order.

Its also more efficient to only ask for the columns that you actually want anyway.

So change the query to

```
$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT idquestion, question, id 
                                    FROM question 
                                    WHERE idquestion=? AND category=?;");
```

Now you are in control of the order the columns are returned.

So when you run this

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "is", $idquestion,  $category);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $idquestion, $question, $id);
```

The columns values will go into the correct variables.

Comment: Indeed that was the issue. now i remember that i changed some columns back when i created the question table, so.. I guess even if the columns order was the same with the variables, they went in the wrong spot.

Comment: selecting each variable solved the problem. thanks a lot